# cannot insert and found the data was store in dynamoDb

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

hi all i have dynamoDb data

like this one

Provisioned read capacity units
100 (Auto Scaling Enabled)
Provisioned write capacity units
237 (Auto Scaling Enabled)
Last decrease time

June 29, 2020 at 9:21:11 AM UTC+7

UTC: June 29, 2020 at 2:21:11 AM UTC

Local: June 29, 2020 at 9:21:11 AM UTC+7

Region (Ohio): June 28, 2020 at 9:21:11 PM UTC-5
Last increase time

June 29, 2020 at 11:23:37 AM UTC+7

UTC: June 29, 2020 at 4:23:37 AM UTC

Local: June 29, 2020 at 11:23:37 AM UTC+7

Region (Ohio): June 28, 2020 at 11:23:37 PM UTC-5
Storage size (in bytes)
4.17 GB
Item count
57,546,905Manage live count
Region
US East (Ohio)

the data are there and i success insert to dynamoDb

but when i try to query i cannot found that... and it is like my dynamoDb cannot read or write the data... why like that ? i insert price data from my broker foreign exchange

here my code when i want insert to my database

```
Integer priceId = ++count;
        String symbols= symbol;
        String price = priceAsString;
        String time = timestampstrings;
        String idPrice = String.valueOf(priceId);  
        String Prefix = "Onezero";
        String idSave = Prefix.concat(idPrice);
            
            //Add Content 
            
            Item item = new Item().withPrimaryKey( "symbol", symbols, "priceId", idSave).withString("Price", price).withString("savetime", time);
            //save to DynamoDb
            table.putItem(item);
            //System.out.println("Success For Insert Data");
```

the data are missing from 16th of june until now. why like that

i want to now how to setup dynamoDb for huge data and fast insert ?